# Tensorflow on Device Training - setting my own dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I am following the following tutorial for doing [on-device image classification using Tensorflow](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/examples/on_device_training/overview.ipynb)

The part where they set the dataset is clear to me (they are using the MNIST Fashion dataset):

```py
fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

I am not clear on how I can switch this to be my own dataset.

I DO have a Google Cloud bucket with my images available publicly, but I can't really figure out how to set that in the python code.

I tried:

```py
fashion_mnist = "https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/bucketname"
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

But that didn't even compile.

Is there a simple way to add my own dataset?

I am thinking there may be an api offered by the `tf` object, but I am not clear even where to look at the API for this class.

I was hoping there might be an API call that is something like this:

```
fashion_mnist = tf.dataset.fromURL("http://...")
```

Comment: No, you have the completely wrong concept on how to load a image dataset, a lot more work is needed.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will research further and figure out what that work is. I appreciate the response @Dr.Snoopy